# Can swagger generate stubs for WebAPI using .net framework 4.5?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger-codegen

I have a swagger specification file that I would like to use to generate stubs for a WebAPI that runs over the .NET Framework 4.5. I already have a project using that framework and I can't change it entirely to use asp net core right now, that is the why I would like to generate the stubs for the 4.5 framework.